# Who does the encoding job for the characters, initializer or the quotation marks?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, encoding

Double quotes yield a string literal and single quotes create a character literal.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s = 'H'; // [Encoding]
    printf("%x\n", s); //prints 48 (hexadecimal number) 
    printf("%c\n", s); //prints H [Decoding]
    return 0;
}
```

**My Understanding So far**

`char` is an integral type which is able to hold an 8-bit number. The process of the definition `char s = 'H'` is a encoding process. It encodes the **H** to the Ascii code index: number 72 (0x48) and saves it in the variable.

The `%c` in the `printf("%c\n", s)` in fact is the decoding process. According to UTF-8 encoding/decoding rules it decodes the ascii index 72 (0x48) to English character 'H'

Now the question comes to the double/single quote

**Assumption**:

The single quote operator does no more than just encoding the character clusters into the Unicode index (while the double quote encodes characters into the Unicode index arrays)

**Question**:

Are my Understandings/assumptions correct? If they are all wrong, please point out.

Comment: Seems correct to me, but with a few nitpickings: `'` and `"` are not operators, and the standard doesn't require implementations to use ASCII and/or Unicode.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat operator is an object that is capable of manipulating a value or operator, but `'` and `"` manipulate the character via encodes it into a number. So, maybe the encoding job is done by the initialize not the quotation mark. .. I think I might in a wrong direction to think this problem

Comment: _" According to UTF-8 encoding/decoding..."_ nope ASCII.  Putting Unicode (any encoding except escape sequences) in source files is asking for trouble.

Comment: @RichardCritten Both are not guaranteed anyway.

Comment: @SLN I don't think it makes sense to reason 'what thing does encoding'. The compiler does it.

Comment: @RichardCritten • not even ASCII is guaranteed.  Could be EBCDIC.  Or something non-standard for a given (probably esoteric) platform.

Comment: The compiler reads the source file using the encoding you tell it to (which is hopefully the encoding you are writing it with). For literal characters, it transcribes them into a char sequence using the encoding that you tell it to. ASCII itself is not widely supported by modern compilers (or source code and text editors for that matter). See -fexec-charset,  /execution-charset or equivalent for your compiler. They have defaults, of course.

Comment: "single quote operator"???? There is no such thing... You may want to find grammar for similar curly-braced language (C is simple enough) and read it to see if there is a better term for whatever you trying to describe.